# Android : String resource not found while trying to get resource in List activity class

Tags: android, string

I am working on an Android project and as I have to test on local machine and on server, I thought of giving a base-url. I keep getting the error as mentioned below. As I checked on SO, this is the way to get URL, what am I doing wrong. Error below and code after that.

```
 07-20 13:19:54.612    3795-3795/com.example.TestLunch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.TestLunch, PID: 3795
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.TestLunch/com.example.TestLunch.Activity.RestaurantList}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f04000e
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f04000e
```

Code throwing error.

```
public class RestaurantList extends ListActivity {

// Below line throws the error.
    String restaurantList = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.baseUrl)+"restaurant/listing";
}
```

Strings.xml :

```
 <string name="baseUrl">http://192.168.178.60:8080/</string>
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

*Update*

This also failed :

```
String restaurantList = getResources().getString(R.string.baseUrl)+"restaurant/listing";
```

*Update*

This also failed

```
public class RestaurantList extends ListActivity{
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restos);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
        String restaurantList = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.baseUrl)+"restaurant/listing";
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use getResources().getString(R.string.baseUrl); ?

Comment: @4k3R : That didn't work in non-activity class, so I started using this.

Comment: @4k3R : Tried, still the error.

Comment: The same works fine for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems :

- You should not access the resources in the constructor or in field initializers, it is too early. The right place is in the `onCreate` methods.
- `Resources.getSystem().getString()` can only find system resources, not the one you define in your application. You should use [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) from the Activity.

In your case :

```
public class RestaurantList extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restos);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
        String restaurantList = getString(R.string.baseUrl) + "restaurant/listing";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
String restaurantList = getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.baseUrl) + "restaurant/listing";
```

Comment: Could it be that you are using multiple strings.xml files ?
Like values/strings.xml and values-v21/strings.xml

Comment: No, I dont, can you check the main post, I have edited it to include what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access at string resource out of method onCreate. If you add your code in the onCreate() method the problem is solved.

like this works

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    String restaurantList = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.baseUrl)+"restaurant/listing";
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an error, please note, the class extends ListActivity, not activity.

Comment: put the onCreate method in the RestaurantList. It's a ListActivity so you can use onCreate.

Comment: I have it, and just that my onCreate method does not have the 2nd parameter as you do, is it required?? Check bottom part of my main post, i have edited it.

Comment: no problem ;) you can use the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) with the first parameter and works anyway!

Comment: It is not working, thats what I just meant with the edit in main post.

Comment: it's not possible. Are you using Android Studio?Or still Eclipse? And than. How do you initialize your listactivity and where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83757/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-br00).